# Show Parent Page Content In Slug Page too - VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

This is my page structure:

```
 ---Pages (directory)
    |---Blog (directory)
        |--- index.vue
        |--- [slug].vue
```

In Index.Vue, I have a blog post listing code And
in [slug].Vue I have a single blog post listing.

What I want to do is, show the post listing in index.Vue as well as in [slug].Vue

Currently, the only way I can do is to call the post listing component in both files manually, I don't want to duplicate code like this, is there any other way for this? maybe something with RouterView v-slot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve the same result with router-view

Set your router file as follows

```js
routes: [
    {
      path: "/blog",
      component: blog, //index.vue
      children: [
        {
          path: ":slug",
          component: post //[slug].vue
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and your index.vue like this

```js
<template>
  <router-view />
  <h1> your posts List </h1>
  //.... your code here 
</template>
```

You can find a demo of this example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-parent-page-content-in-slug-dgvml9?file=/src/router.js).